# How does one make a button in the main window open a different window?

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I am very new to this and have used the Qt Designer to make a very simple main window ui. The first functionality I want in my project is for a button to open a different window when clicked.

So basically I have the file `autoGenUI.py` that is generated using pyside-uic which includes

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class AutoGeneratedUI(object): 
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        #Auto generated code

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        #Auto generated code
```

This all works fine of course because the Qt designer made it. I then have my own .py file that is basically my application stuff.

It looks like this:

```
import sys

from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

from autoGenUI import *

class MyMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = AutoGeneratedUI()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myMainWindow = MyMainWindow()
    myMainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My button is called `self.pushButton` in the auto generated python UI. I would like to design another window and then call that window but for now anything will do. I just don't know where to put the code to make my button do something.

I tried to follow the [docs](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Signals_and_Slots_in_PySide) but couldn't get anything to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect the clicked signal of pushButton to a method such as on_button_clicked():

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
    self.ui = AutoGeneratedUI()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    # connect the clicked signal to on_button_clicked() method
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_button_clicked) 

def on_button_clicked(self):
    print "button clicked"
    # here is the code to open a new window
```

Comment: I actually just figured out what I was doing wrong. Right about this line `self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_button_clicked)` I was "redeclaring" the button like this `self.pushButton = QPushButton()`

I feel dumb but thank you.